# Space between columns in Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart where for each X value I have two series.
But the graph shows a wide spacing between each X value.

How can I do in Highchart to have 1px space between the columns and the y Axis?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Update `pointPadding :0.2 to pointPadding :0`
in

```
plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
```

Comment: For an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-pointpadding-025/

Answer (score 4):

```
chart: {
    marginBottom: 1,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    marginTop: 0,
    renderTo: container,
    type: 'column',
},
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gTaZ9/273/)

Also check [GroupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.groupPadding) and [PointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding)