# Reducing spacing in between columns in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to reduce the space in between the red columns. Please refer to [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/foursides/5q9fh164/2/)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    colors: ['#ba0000'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        spacingBottom: 10,
        spacingTop: 30,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 10,

        style: {
            fontFamily: 'MuseoSans-500',
            fontSize: '14px'                
        }       

    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'YTD',
            'QTD',
            'Last Period'
        ],
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize:'14px'
            }
        }           
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: '%'
        },

        plotLines: [{
            color: '#0054a6',
            width: 2,
            value: 48,
            dashStyle: 'Dash',
        label : {
                    text : 'AVG'
                }               
        },



        {
            color: '#00ed99',
            width: 2,
            value: 65,
            dashStyle: 'Dash',
            label : {
                    text : 'GOAL',

             }  


            }]

    },



    credits: {
         enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:1.1em">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0"></td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}%</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {

            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointWidth: 50,
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [57, 63, 62],


    }]
});
```

});

I have tried solutions from [Highcharts - How can I decrease space between categories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142378/highcharts-how-can-i-decrease-space-between-categories) and [Space between columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220619/space-between-columns) but it didn't quite work. I'm not too sure what I am missing out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You need the property `groupPadding`

```
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0,
            }
        },
```

This will completely remove the spacing between them.

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/5q9fh164/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, but that will overlap the two dashed plot lines which are in green and blue. Is there any way to reduce the space but not overlap those lines.

Comment: @square lines are poisitoned according to value which you defined. So if you need them higher, set different value.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I had a column stockChart with very thin columns that were almost impossible to mouse over, this was perfect!

Comment: @square Please refer bellow link , in this distance between column  and group column is nicely calculated , by this  no column will overlap to each other or will not create major gap between column

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/77